# Slice and concatenate dataframe efficiently in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with `id`, `event` and `metric` columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','x', 1], 
                  ['a','x',2],  
                  ['b','x',3],
                  ['b','x',3],
                  ['a','z',4],  
                  ['a','z',5],
                  ['b','y',5]], columns = ['id','event','metric'])


   id event metric
0   a   x   1
1   a   x   2
2   b   x   3
3   b   x   3
4   a   z   4
5   a   z   5
6   b   y   5
```

I need to find the last `event` in each `id` and get the row with this `event` plus all the rows above with this `id`. The resulting dataframe should be the concatenation of such slices with the following columns:

1. index in the original df
2. new id formed as 'id we used to get
   the filtered slice' + 'the last event in the filtered slice'

Desired output:

```
  index new_id
0   0   ax
1   1   ax
2   2   bx
3   3   bx
4   0   az
5   1   az
6   4   az
7   5   az
8   2   by
9   3   by
10  6   by
```

I produced the desired output with the following code:

```
df['id_event'] = df.id + df.event
id_events = df.id_event.unique()
df_all = pd.DataFrame()


for i,id_event in (enumerate(id_events)):
    id = id_event[:1]
    event = id_event[1:]
    last_row_id = df[df.event==event].iloc[-1].name
    temp = df.iloc[: last_row_id +1][df.id==id]
    temp['new_id'] = id_event

    df_all = pd.concat([df_all, temp.reset_index()], axis=0, sort=False)


df_all.reset_index()[['index', 'new_id']]
```

The problem is I have around 20M rows, so it takes around 20 hours to get the result. I'm trying to solve this in efficient way, e.g. without loops.

Answer (score 0):

The main performance problem is you're calling `pd.concat()` on every iteration, which is expensive.  Try this:

```
results = [] # added
for i,id_event in (enumerate(id_events)):
    id = id_event[:1]
    event = id_event[1:]
    last_row_id = df[df.event==event].iloc[-1].name
    temp = df.iloc[: last_row_id +1][df.id==id]
    temp['new_id'] = id_event
    results.append(temp.reset_index()) # changed

df_all = pd.concat(results, sort=False) # changed
```

This should save a lot of time--let us know how much.

Also note that `df[df.event==event].iloc[-1].name` can be more simply written as `df[df.event==event].index[-1]`.

Comment: I've tried your code. When there's 100k rows, your code works 6x faster. But when feed 1M rows and more to it, the performance is roughly the same. It just gets very slow when it comes to filtering. `df[df.event==event].iloc[-1].name` and `df.iloc[: last_row_id +1][df.id==id]` last around 100 ms each. That's where almost all the time is spent @John Zwinck